# Create knockout computed with Underscore.js groupBy & map for select control

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, knockout.js, underscore.js

I am trying to create a partial view that will display a select control with grouped options.

I have an initial bit of JSON:

```
[{
    "customFrequencyId": 1008,
    "startDate": "2016-10-29T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2016-11-25T00:00:00Z",
    "label": "P11 2016"
}, {
    "customFrequencyId": 1008,
    "startDate": "2016-11-26T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2016-12-31T00:00:00Z",
    "label": "P12 2016"
}, {
    "customFrequencyId": 1008,
    "startDate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2017-01-28T00:00:00Z",
    "label": "P1 2017"
}, {
    "customFrequencyId": 1008,
    "startDate": "2017-01-29T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2017-02-25T00:00:00Z",
    "label": "P2 2017"
}, {
    "customFrequencyId": 1008,
    "startDate": "2017-02-26T00:00:00Z",
    "endDate": "2017-03-23T00:00:00Z",
    "label": "P3 2017"
}]
```

My current TypeScript:

```
export class CustomPeriodSelection {

    customPeriods: KnockoutObservable<any[]> = ko.observable([]);
    selectedOption: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();

    customGroups: KnockoutComputed<any[]> = ko.computed(() => {
        var groupedList = _.groupBy(this.customPeriods(), function (item: any) {
            return item.endDate.substring(0, 4);
        });

        return _.map(groupedList, function (item: any) {
            return item;
        });
    });

    constructor(
        customPeriods: any[]
    ) {
        this.customPeriods(customPeriods);
    }
}
```

My intention is to end up with the following JSON from the Knockout computed...

```
[{
    "label": 2016,
    "customPeriods": [{
        "customFrequencyId": 1008,
        "startDate": "2016-10-29T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2016-11-25T00:00:00Z",
        "label": "P11 2016"
    }, {
        "customFrequencyId": 1008,
        "startDate": "2016-11-26T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2016-12-31T00:00:00Z",
        "label": "P12 2016"
    }]
}, {
    "label": 2017,
    "customPeriods": [{
        "customFrequencyId": 1008,
        "startDate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2017-01-28T00:00:00Z",
        "label": "P1 2017"
    }, {
        "customFrequencyId": 1008,
        "startDate": "2017-01-29T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2017-02-25T00:00:00Z",
        "label": "P2 2017"
    }, {
        "customFrequencyId": 1008,
        "startDate": "2017-02-26T00:00:00Z",
        "endDate": "2017-03-23T00:00:00Z",
        "label": "P3 2017"
    }]
}]
```

Which will then be put to the select control like this..

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: customGroups, event: { change: periodChanged }">
    <optgroup data-bind="attr: { label: $data.label}, foreach: customPeriods">
        <option data-bind="text: $data.label, value: $data"></option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I'm assuming it is the implementation of groupBy & map that are incorrect. How do I group the customPeriods array by year, and then map the result to a new array with the required structure above?

I currently get the following from the code I have written.

```
[
  [
    {
      "customFrequencyId": 1008,
      "startDate": "2016-10-29T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2016-11-25T00:00:00Z",
      "label": "P11 2016"
    },
    {
      "customFrequencyId": 1008,
      "startDate": "2016-11-26T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2016-12-31T00:00:00Z",
      "label": "P12 2016"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "customFrequencyId": 1008,
      "startDate": "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2017-01-28T00:00:00Z",
      "label": "P1 2017"
    },
    {
      "customFrequencyId": 1008,
      "startDate": "2017-01-29T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2017-02-25T00:00:00Z",
      "label": "P2 2017"
    },
    {
      "customFrequencyId": 1008,
      "startDate": "2017-02-26T00:00:00Z",
      "endDate": "2017-03-23T00:00:00Z",
      "label": "P3 2017"
    }
  ]
]
```

I have read other questions but I'm struggling. Any help would be greatly appreciated (with an explanation if possible as opposed to just doing it for me). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.

Change:

```
return _.map(groupedList, function (item: any) {
            return item;
        });
```

to

```
return _.map(groupedList, function (item: any) {
            return { label: item[0].endDate.substring(0, 4), customPeriods: item };
        });
```

Though I'd like to verify this in a plunker first.